# How to select parent rows that doesn't have child and child that has parent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a little bit complicated query. 
I have table

```
tbl_Categories {CategoryID, Name, CategoryId_fk}
```

and it it a **self referenced table**.
When `CategoryId_fk` is `NULL` then that row is **parent** when there is a value that it is a **child**.
I have problem to select all children (it's where `CategoryId_fk` is not `null`) and rows where `CategoryId_fk` is `null` and doesn't have children.
I tried something but doesn't work:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl_Categories a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tbl_Categories b
    WHERE b.CategoryId_fk= a.CategoryId_fk
)
```

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "Recursive CTE" for dozens of examples of how to solve problems like this. [edit] Toss in "hierarchy" for more specific examples.

Comment: Umm.. I think I didnt get it right. if you want all children & all parents, wouldnt that be whole table?
Can you provide sample data?

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel - The whole table *without* parents who *have* children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have matched both `b` and `a` on the foreign key.

I might be misinterpreting your question, most of the times users want to find all childs for a given parent, but  below query returns what I think you need.

```
/* All parents without children */
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tbl_Categories a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * 
          FROM   tbl_Categories b
          WHERE  b.CategoryId_fk = a.CategoryId
)
/* All children */
UNION ALL
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tbl_Categories a
WHERE   CategoryId_fk IS NOT NULL
```